# How to use transition functions in mongoose "another-mongoose-statemachine" module

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
var statemachine = require('another-mongoose-statemachine');
launchSchema.plugin(statemachine,{
states:{
    draft : {default :true},
    published: {},
    launched : {},
    postponed : {},
    rejected: {},
},
transitions : {
    publish : {from: 'draft', to: 'published', behavior: transPublish},
    postpone : {from: 'published', to: 'postponed'},
    launch : {from: 'published', to: 'launched'},
    reject: {from: 'published', to: 'rejected'}
}
});
```

How Can I use publish method and transPublish method?
Some Queries: When I change state from draft to published, will this method get called automatically or I have to call them.

Comment: Dude you should not post the code from repository.

Comment: This is not answer sir!!! I asked question from a open source repo. Your answer is very welcome :P